# can I loop some data json with nested value

Tags: json, go

When I got a new data json ORDER_TRX_H_ID the result must looping with new ORDER_TRX_H_ID, but my result always show last data.

My code is

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    dataJSON := `[
{
    "QUICK_DATA_H_ID": "1",
    "ORDER_TRX_H_ID": "1",
    "FIELD_QUESTION": "FULLNAME",
    "FIELD_ANSWER": "RUBEN",
    "DTM_CRT": "2019-08-28T16:25:15.757Z"
},
{
    "QUICK_DATA_H_ID": "2",
    "ORDER_TRX_H_ID": "1",
    "FIELD_QUESTION": "ALAMAT_KTP",
    "FIELD_ANSWER": "jalandisana",
    "DTM_CRT": "2019-08-28T16:25:15.757Z"
},
{
    "QUICK_DATA_H_ID": "3",
    "ORDER_TRX_H_ID": "2",
    "FIELD_QUESTION": "FULLNAME",
    "FIELD_ANSWER": "Fariz",
    "DTM_CRT": "2019-08-28T16:25:15.757Z"
},
{
    "QUICK_DATA_H_ID": "4",
    "ORDER_TRX_H_ID": "2",
    "FIELD_QUESTION": "ALAMAT_KTP",
    "FIELD_ANSWER": "Bogor",
    "DTM_CRT": "2019-08-28T16:25:15.757Z"
}
    ]`
    var data []map[string]interface{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(dataJSON), &data)
    qa := map[string]interface{}{}
    for _, v := range data {
        qa[v["FIELD_QUESTION"].(string)] = v["FIELD_ANSWER"]
    }
    hasil := data[0]
    hasil["QUESTION"] = qa
    delete(hasil, "FIELD_QUESTION")
    delete(hasil, "FIELD_ANSWER")
    hasilJSON, _ := json.MarshalIndent(hasil, "", "  ")
    fmt.Println(string(hasilJSON))
}
```

You can run my code 
https://play.golang.org/p/aHUoYZlEQs4

My result always show last data

```
{
  "DTM_CRT": "2019-08-28T16:25:15.757Z",
  "ORDER_TRX_H_ID": "1",
  "QUESTION": {
    "ALAMAT_KTP": "Bogor",
    "FULLNAME": "Fariz"
  },
  "QUICK_DATA_H_ID": "1"
}
```

my expected result

```
{
  "DTM_CRT": "2019-08-28T16:25:15.757Z",
  "ORDER_TRX_H_ID": "1",
  "QUESTION": {
    "ALAMAT_KTP": "jalandisana",
    "FULLNAME": "RUBEN"
  },
  "QUICK_DATA_H_ID": "1"
},
{
  "DTM_CRT": "2019-08-28T16:25:15.757Z",
  "ORDER_TRX_H_ID": "2",
  "QUESTION": {
    "ALAMAT_KTP": "Bogor",
    "FULLNAME": "Fariz"
  },
  "QUICK_DATA_H_ID": "2"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why your result only showing 1 data? it because of this line of code:

```golang
hasil := data[0]
```

`hasil` will always have just one element

also `qa` will only contains value like this:

```
{
  "ALAMAT_KTP": "BOGOR",
  "FULLNAME": "Fariz"
}
```

it because every `data` iteration, `qa[v["FIELD_QUESTION"].(string)]` will keep replaced due to `v["FIELD_QUESTION"].(string)` is no unique, so in the 3rd iteration of `data`, the `qa["ALAMAT_KTP]` that already have value `"jalandisana"` is replaced with `qa["ALAMAT_KTP] = "Bogor"`

I modified your code here: https://play.golang.org/p/Ca4aGPGJwT7

I use 2 `map[string]map[string]interface{}` to hold `qa` and `modified data`
and then I combine them into one

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    dataJSON := `[
        {
            "QUICK_DATA_H_ID": "1",
            "ORDER_TRX_H_ID": "1",
            "FIELD_QUESTION": "FULLNAME",
            "FIELD_ANSWER": "RUBEN",
            "DTM_CRT": "2019-08-28T16:25:15.757Z"
        },
        {
            "QUICK_DATA_H_ID": "2",
            "ORDER_TRX_H_ID": "1",
            "FIELD_QUESTION": "ALAMAT_KTP",
            "FIELD_ANSWER": "jalandisana",
            "DTM_CRT": "2019-08-28T16:25:15.757Z"
        },
        {
            "QUICK_DATA_H_ID": "3",
            "ORDER_TRX_H_ID": "2",
            "FIELD_QUESTION": "FULLNAME",
            "FIELD_ANSWER": "Fariz",
            "DTM_CRT": "2019-08-28T16:25:15.757Z"
        },
        {
            "QUICK_DATA_H_ID": "4",
            "ORDER_TRX_H_ID": "2",
            "FIELD_QUESTION": "ALAMAT_KTP",
            "FIELD_ANSWER": "Bogor",
            "DTM_CRT": "2019-08-28T16:25:15.757Z"
        }
    ]`

    var data, finalResult []map[string]interface{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(dataJSON), &data)

    qa := map[string]map[string]interface{}{}
    res := map[string]map[string]interface{}{}

    for _, v := range data {
        if qa[v["ORDER_TRX_H_ID"].(string)] == nil {
            // initialize the map first if map is nil
            qa[v["ORDER_TRX_H_ID"].(string)] = make(map[string]interface{})
        }
        qa[v["ORDER_TRX_H_ID"].(string)][v["FIELD_QUESTION"].(string)] = v["FIELD_ANSWER"]

        delete(v, "FIELD_QUESTION")
        delete(v, "FIELD_ANSWER")

        // only assign res if res[key] is nil to prevent doubled data
        if res[v["ORDER_TRX_H_ID"].(string)] == nil {
            res[v["ORDER_TRX_H_ID"].(string)] = v
        }
    }

    // combine qa and res in finalResult
    for k, v := range res {
        v["QUESTION"] = qa[k]
        finalResult = append(finalResult, v)
    }

    hasilJSON, _ := json.MarshalIndent(finalResult, "", "  ")

    fmt.Println(string(hasilJSON))
}
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "DTM_CRT": "2019-08-28T16:25:15.757Z",
    "ORDER_TRX_H_ID": "1",
    "QUESTION": {
      "ALAMAT_KTP": "jalandisana",
      "FULLNAME": "RUBEN"
    },
    "QUICK_DATA_H_ID": "1"
  },
  {
    "DTM_CRT": "2019-08-28T16:25:15.757Z",
    "ORDER_TRX_H_ID": "2",
    "QUESTION": {
      "ALAMAT_KTP": "Bogor",
      "FULLNAME": "Fariz"
    },
    "QUICK_DATA_H_ID": "3"
  }
]
```

Comment: big thanks mas Rama, saya coba implementasikan dulu :D